# Phalcon webtools loading wrong url

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon

I am just getting started with phalcon and I have installed webtools. When I load up the page http://www.example.com/webstools.php the webtools dashboard is displayed, but when I click any of the links the url:

http://www.example.com/webtools.php/webtools.php?xxxxxx

so basically all the pages are adding webtools.php, I am not sure how to correct this, the config file is as follows:

```
<?php


defined('PTOOLS_IP') || define('PTOOLS_IP', '192.168.');
defined('BASE_PATH') || define('BASE_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
defined('APP_PATH') || define('APP_PATH', BASE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app');

defined('ENV_PRODUCTION') || define('ENV_PRODUCTION', 'production');

defined('ENV_STAGING') || define('ENV_STAGING', 'staging');

defined('ENV_DEVELOPMENT') || define('ENV_DEVELOPMENT', 'development');

defined('ENV_TESTING') || define('ENV_TESTING', 'testing');

defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: ENV_DEVELOPMENT);

// ---------------------------- DO NOT EDIT BELOW ------------------------------

/**
 * @const PTOOLSPATH The path to the Phalcon Developers Tools.
 */
defined('PTOOLSPATH') || define('PTOOLSPATH', '/var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools');
```

Thanks in advance - BTW I'm am running on Ubuntu 16.04 with nginx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `baseUri` to `'/'` in your app/config/config.php should fix this problem.

https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/issues/1215